# Передача массива с сервера стандартными средствами JS и PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, массивы

Всем привет!
*Логика приложения:*
Строительством HTML управляет JS. При первичном обращении приходит стандартная страница, в зависимости от **действий пользователя** JS меняет её соответствующим образом.
*Проблема:*
 эти **действия** влекут за собой запросы на сервер, где PHP вытягивает данные из БД и формирует массив ключ-значение. Теперь не знаю как передать этот массив в JS, минуя JQuery или другие сторонние библиотеки.
В JS - новичок, очень хочу, пока, обойтись стандартными средствами.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Для новичка в самый раз jquery подойдёт, пока будете разбираться с чистым js.

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Можно сделать так:

В своем php файле, например post.php, получи нужный тебе массив с данными:

```
<?php

$postData = array(
  "error" => '123',
  "successInfo" => 'peivet',
  "email" => 'tets@gmail.com',
);

echo json_encode($postData);
```

После этого в своем js файле, для примера script.js, ты можешь получить весь свой массив с данными из своего post.php файла.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'post.php',
    success: function(result) {
      var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

});
```

Ну и все, а теперь у тебя в переменной var data есть все необходимое, делай уже что нужно на стороне клиента :) И это все, можешь сразу делать в функции success.

Comment: Спасибо. Но до конца не понял))) То есть я сформировал массив - преобразовал в json. А как дальше будет ловить его JS на стороне клиента?